# How to read context-param (web.xml) values in a resources.groovy grails 2.3

Tags: spring, grails

I need to get context-param values from a web.xml to override values in a resources.groovy.
The Grails documentation purpose just to use a placeholder with a property file but the solution is not appropriate because in the future I want to use deployment plan with weblogic to override the context-param for different environnement. It's impossible to use ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer because is deprecated now. Have you a solution ?

Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure about the groovey stuff, but you could still use a property-placeholder: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21175824/1669464

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, add webXml plugin into your Grails Project. This plugin add possibility to add context-param after the web.xml generation in the war. 
create YOUR-APP/grails-app/conf/WebXmlConfig.groovy, and override :

```
webxml {
    filterChainProxyDelegator.add = false
    filterChainProxyDelegator.targetBeanName = "filterChainProxyDelegate"
    filterChainProxyDelegator.urlPattern = "/*"
    filterChainProxyDelegator.filterName = "filterChainProxyDelegator"
    filterChainProxyDelegator.className = "org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy"

    listener.add = false
    //listener.classNames = ["org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener"]

    contextparams = [sample: 'Sample Value'] // Add your context param

//  sessionConfig.sessionTimeout = 30
}
```

after that, in your resources.groovy, you can use org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.ServletContextHolder.getServletContext()

I saw the solution here: [accessing-servletContext-in-resources-groovy](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/accessing-servletContext-in-resources-groovy-td1313892.html)

You call getInitParameter method to get values declared in the web.xml.

```
beans = {

ServletContext sc= org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.ServletContextHolder.getServletContext()
String value = sc.getInitParameter('sample')

}
```

It can help you